# Use matrix types as fragment shader output in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

In OpenGL, a matrix takes up multiple locations in a shader (one for each column). So when using a matrix in a vertex shader as an input it is necessary to call `glVertexAttribPointer()` multiple times.

I am wondering if it is possible to do something similar for matrix types as outputs in a fragment shader when rendering to multiple framebuffers. That is, I would have 4 different textures in a frame buffer bound to color attachments 0 through 3, and then I could have a `layout(location = 0) out matrix4 out_mat` that I could write to with the fragment shader.

Am I correct in assuming that this would work?

Comment: You can writhe ach column of the matrix to a different target (plane), of the buffer. `out0 = m[0];` `out1 = m[1];` ...

Comment: So does that mean that this doesn't work?

Comment: @InformationAether: "*In OpenGL, a matrix takes up multiple locations in a shader*" Matrices only take more than one location when used as *vertex shader inputs*. In every other case where they can be used (intra-shader in/out variables, uniforms), they only take up one location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the output of a fragment shader, a matrix data type is not allowed :

See [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification - 4.3.6. Output Variables](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf), page 54:

> Fragment outputs output per-fragment data and are declared using the `out` storage qualifier. It is a compile-time error to use auxiliary storage qualifiers or interpolation qualifiers in a fragment shader output declaration. **It is a compile-time error to declare a fragment shader output with, or that contains, any of the following types**:
>
> - A boolean type
> - A double-precision scalar or vector (double, dvec2, dvec3, dvec4)
> - An opaque type
> - **A matrix type**
> - A structure

---

But the output of a fragment shader is allowed to be an array:

e.g.

```c
layout (location = 0) out vec4 fragOut[4];

void main()
{
    mat4 m = [...];

    fragOut[0] = m[0];
    fragOut[1] = m[1];
    [...]
}
```

The matrix can be assigned to the array by an array constructor (see [4.1.13. Arrays](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf), page 36):

```c
layout (location = 0) out vec4 fragOut[4];

void main()
{
    mat4 m = [...];

    fragOut = vec4[4](m[0], m[1], m[2], m[3]);
}
```

Comment: Do you know if arrays of vectors are allowed though? Couldn't find it in the spec.

Comment: @ybungalobill It is not expressly forbidden. In general an output variable can be an array. I just tried it and it works.

Answer (score 2):

GLSL spec says (Version 4.5, 4.3.6 Output Variables):

> It is a compile-time error to declare a fragment shader output that contains any of the following:
>
> ...
>
> - Any matrix type

Therefore

```
layout(location = 0) out mat4 out_mat;
```

is illegal.

Instead you should output the elements of the matrix into four separate outputs:

```
 layout(location = 0) out vec4 out_mat0;
 layout(location = 1) out vec4 out_mat1;
 layout(location = 2) out vec4 out_mat2;
 layout(location = 3) out vec4 out_mat3;

 void main() {
     mat4 M = ...;
     out_mat0 = M[0]; // column 0
     out_mat1 = M[1]; // column 1
     out_mat2 = M[2]; // column 2
     out_mat3 = M[3]; // column 3
 }
```